# How to get store one specific element of a JSON post response in Swift

Tags: swift, http, networking

I have a swift program that creates a successful JSON post to a rails application. This is the response:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x604000226280> { URL: http://groupsyncenv.rtimfc7m2.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/login_post } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
    "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
);
Connection =     (
    close
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    618
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Wed, 24 Jan 2018 17:57:52 GMT"
);
Etag =     (
    "W/\"c34b1ba0f3cfbd53ef65a30eddd47c50\""
);
Server =     (
    "nginx/1.12.1"
);
Via =     (
    "1.1 m00180A4E4E3C (squid/3.5.23)"
);
"X-Cache" =     (
    "MISS from m00180A4E4E3C"
);
"X-Cache-Lookup" =     (
    "MISS from m00180A4E4E3C:3128"
);
"X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
    nosniff
);
"X-Frame-Options" =     (
    SAMEORIGIN
);
"X-Request-Id" =     (
    "9bf3c1fa-e362-4d59-8396-8540981f1d36"
);
"X-Runtime" =     (
    "0.092878"
);
"X-XSS-Protection" =     (
    "1; mode=block"
);
```

All I need from this code is the number associated with the response "X-Request-Id" but I'm not sure how to do it. My swift program is below:

```
func loginPost(){

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Postman-Token": "b5468cec-292a-6c60-d195-6e270909e54b"
    ]
    let parameters = [
        "email": "sample@email.com",
        "password": "password123"
        ] as [String : Any]

    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    guard let data = postData else {
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://groupsyncenv.rtimfc7um2.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/login_post")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData as? Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()

}
```

As you can see I'm just printing the Http response which I know is wrong but I can't figure out how to access individual elements here. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @creeperspeak OP didn't ask about JSON parsing, rather asked about how to handle the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the HTTP headers after casting the `URLResponse` object to `HTTPURLResponse` by calling `response.allHeaderFields`, which is a `Dictionary`, so you can use subscription to get the value corresponding to a specific key.

Some generic advice: don't use old `Foundation` data types unless you have a very good reason to do so. Use their native Swift alternatives. This is especially true when you are casting the `Foundation` objects to their Swift alternatives right after creating them, since the Swift APIs expect Swift types, such as `URLRequest` rather than `NSMutableURLRequest` and `URL` instead of `NSURL`.

```
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
]
let parameters = [
    "email": "sample@email.com",
    "password": "password123"
    ] as [String : Any]

let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://groupsyncenv.rtimfc7um2.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/login_post")!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
    } else if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let requestId = response.allHeaderFields["X-Request-Id"] as? String
        print(requestId)
    }
}).resume()
```